# java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.print.Win32PrintService

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, serialization

I am using the Persistent Manager Implementation on the tomcat server with a JDBC Store, Which stores the session data in the DB table instead of storing in tomcat. When i go through the application it throws `NotSerializableException` several times for several classes. The exception for the classes or objects in the project files is easy to solve. But some times this error appears for the the non project files like the error shown below. Most of the `NotSerializableException`  for non project classes of spring and various other dependencies solved by adding `transient` at there reference. But i coudn't find a reference  to remove this `Win32PrintService` from session or is it possible to make this service `Serializable`. Someone please help.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.print.Win32PrintService
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder.writeObject(AjaxStateHolder.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at com.erp.common.util.MyAttributeListener.serializableCheck(MyAttributeListener.java:73)
        at com.erp.common.util.MyAttributeListener.attributeReplaced(MyAttributeListener.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1510)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1413)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.setAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:149)
        at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(ExternalContextImpl.java:984)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder.updateInstance(AjaxStateHolder.java:108)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder.saveState(AjaxStateHolder.java:189)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.saveStateInSession(AjaxStateManager.java:539)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.buildViewState(AjaxStateManager.java:519)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.saveSerializedView(AjaxStateManager.java:467)
        at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:615)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.erp.security.HttpThreadLogFilter.doFilter(HttpThreadLogFilter.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at com.erp.security.acegi.CustomLogoutFilter.doFilter(CustomLogoutFilter.java:32)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.PersistentValve.invoke(PersistentValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I couldn't find a reference to remove this `Win32PrintService` from session.

Assuming that this an `HttpSession` object, calling `session.removeAttribute(name)` with the appropriate session attribute name will remove the attribute's value.

However, you need to do this before the session is persisted, and I don't know if there is a way to ensure that happens.

> Is it possible to make this service `Serializable`.

No.  But you could create a `Serializable` wrapper; e.g.

```
  public class PrintServiceWrapper implements PrintService, Serializable {
      private final transient PrintService ps;

      public PrintServiceWrapper(PrintService ps) {
          this.ps = ps;
      }

      // Delegate all PrintService methods to 'ps' 

      // Implement `private void readObject()` to (somehow) reinstate the
      // value of 'ps' ...
  }
```

But this isn't the correct solution, IMO.

The correct way to fix this problem is to not put a `PrintService` object into the session in the first place!

One alternative is to store it as a `ServletContext` attribute instead.  While it is not specified in the javadocs, it looks like `PrintService` implementation classes are designed to be thread-safe.  So it should be possible to safely share a single `PrintService` instance between multiple request threads.

A second alternative is that each request could use a `PrintServiceLookup` call to obtain a `PrintService` instance *when it needs one*.

Comment: That is not a session object. I just created a new class PrintServiceWrapper but this method is not executing. Also I am getting NotSerializableException for net.sf.dozer.util.mapping.cache.CacheEntry so how can i create a wrapper for classes like this which do not implements any interface

Comment: Either way, a PrintService object is inherently unserializable, so you shouldn't put a reference to one in *anything* that needs to be serialized.   And the same applies to `CacheEntry` objects.   It seems like you have some architectural problems in your code that need to be solved ... if random stuff is getting included in your serializations.